# Text-to-speech for Windows 10 PC name

Tags: windows-10, speech-synthesis, bluetooth

I'm looking for a software recommendation for a bash script or similar and perhaps an accompanying text-to-speech program to make a PC name 'readable' by devices.

I have a bluetooth speaker that has no visual display, so uses speech to inform you when devices are connected or disconnected. When I connect a phone to it, the speaker will read the device name and say "Nexus 5" or "Alice's iPhone". However, if I connect my Windows 10 PC to it, the speaker just spells out the name: "A - L - I - C - E", which is not quite as slick. Because the speaker can say names of certain devices but not the PC even if they have the same name, I assume there's some text-to-speech style software installed on the devices that allow the speakers to 'read' the name.

Can anyone recommend a text-to-speech program and/or script that can change the PC name so it is 'readable' to the bluetooth speaker?

Comment: Wouldn’t the speaker have recordings of known names (like "Nexus") and use the (spelling each letter out) text-to-speech way for every unknown name?

Comment: @unor I thought that might be the case but if I were to change my laptop name to Nexus it would still spell it out.

Comment: Do you want to close the question, as it was apparently a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can actually be done witout extra software:

In Windows, go to Device Manager, and open the properties of the Bluetooth Adapter installed. The Advanced tab contains a field called Name for the radio information. The default seems to be to use the device name with all caps, which makes it spell each letter out. However, if we just type it up normally, disconnect the device and pair it again, it spells out the name properly